# Custom Calendar through Graphics & Paint Event

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, paint

This is a little project for myself, just learning graphics for WinForms and so on.

The goal is to program my own Calendar control which will meet some very specific requirements.

Here's how I handle the Paint Event (very hacky atm):

```
    private void XCalendar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Pen
        var pen_border = new Pen(BorderColorGrid);
        var pen_row_border = new Pen(BorderColorGridRow);
        var pen_column_border = new Pen(BorderColorGridColumn);

        //var grid_pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        var bez_pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(192, 241, 231));

        var description_row_height = 30;
        var description_column_width = 65;

        // Calculate Full 
        int full_width = this.Width - 1 - description_column_width;
        int full_height = this.Height - 1 - description_row_height;

        if (this.Users.Count == 0)
        {
            var s = "Keine Benutzer gefunden.";
            var f = new Font(new FontFamily("Trebuchet MS"), 12f);
            var s_size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(s, f);
            var p = new Point((int)(full_width / 2) - (int)(s_size.Width / 2) + 30, 30);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(s, f, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(180, 180, 180)), p);
            return;
        }

        // Calculate Rows
        int row_count = 0;
        switch (_calendarView)
        {
            case CalendarViews.Day:
                row_count = 1;
                break;
            case CalendarViews.Week:
                row_count = 7;
                break;
            case CalendarViews.Month:
                row_count = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
                break;
        }
        int row_height = full_height / row_count;

        // Calculate Columns
        int col_count = Users.Count;
        int col_width = full_width / col_count;

        // Draw Description Column BackColor
        var desc_col_rect = new Rectangle(new Point(1, description_row_height + 1), new Size(description_column_width - 1, full_height - 1));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bez_pen.Color), desc_col_rect);

        // Draw Border
        var rect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen_border, rect);

        var desc_font = new Font(new FontFamily("Trebuchet MS"), 9f);
        var desc_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        // Draw Columns
        var col_x = description_column_width;
        for (int x = 0; x < col_count; x++)
        {
            var rect_col = new Rectangle(new Point(col_x, 1), new Size(col_width, description_row_height));
            var user = Users[x];
            var short_name = user.Shortname;
            var desc_size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(short_name, desc_font);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(user.Color), rect_col);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen_column_border, new Point(col_x, 0), new Point(col_x, full_height + description_row_height));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(short_name, desc_font, desc_brush, new Point(col_x + (int)(col_width / 2 - desc_size.Width / 2), (int)(description_row_height / 2 - desc_size.Height / 2)));

            col_x += col_width;
        }

        // Draw Rows
        var row_y = description_row_height;
        DateTime dt = this.StartDateTime == null ? DateTime.Now : StartDateTime;
        switch (this._calendarView)
        {
            case CalendarViews.Week:
                dt = DateTimeExtensions.StartOfWeek(dt, DayOfWeek.Monday);
                break;
            case CalendarViews.Month:
                dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
                break;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row_count; x++)
        {
            var rect_row = new Rectangle(new Point(1, row_y), new Size(description_column_width - 1, row_height));
            var s = new DateTimeFormatInfo().GetShortestDayName(dt.DayOfWeek) + ", " + dt.ToString("dd.MM");
            var cur_row_fill_color = Color.Transparent;
            if (dt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                cur_row_fill_color = this.FillColorCurrentDateRow;
            }
            else if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                cur_row_fill_color = this.FillColorWeekendDays;
            }
            var s_size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(s, desc_font);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cur_row_fill_color), rect_row);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen_row_border, new Point(0, row_y), new Point(full_width + description_column_width, row_y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(s, desc_font, desc_brush, new Point((int)(description_column_width / 2 - s_size.Width / 2), row_y + 3));

            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            row_y += row_height;
        }
    }
```

Which works absolutely fine (design-wise):
[image]

The calendar will handle multiple users:
[image]

Now of course, this is just a simple grid and some rectangles. Unfortunately I cannot use any event with rectangles since it is solely a painted component.

I was hoping to get some input here on how I could handle clickable calendar items (like appointments). Putting Panels or UserControls everywhere sounds pretty damn inefficient to me...? Any input will be apreciated!

Comment: Is there any possibility you could share a project via github? It would allow more thorough inspection of the code setup and benefit the specificity of suggestions here.

Comment: @NateW Ya, here ya go -> https://github.com/dohueg/NickX.Dozentenplanung

Comment: Is there something missing? The compiler doesn't like the references to `<Reference Include="NickX.WinForms.Transitions">`

Comment: Oh, yeah, that one was an external reference. You should be able to find it in the output-folder tho. (bin/debug/...)

Comment: Bro, you're past my level. You're doing good work with your program, and I haven't built anything that gives me insight into how you could programmatically handle your appointment creation. Full disclosure: I use DevExpress pre-fab tools. I haven't hand-made anything this complicated.

Comment: I use DevExpress Components too in my work environment. Unfortunately I don't like the outdated look from DevEx. Even with the Fluent Design Skin, some controls, especially the calendar controls just look terribly outdated. That's why I want to get into custom painting and stuff :)

Comment: You're doing a great job! Best of luck.

Comment: @NateW You sound like you've been a great teacher :D thanks for you time though!